# prolog to display multiple mysql records in web

Tags: mysql, web, prolog

Sorry for my English. I want to create a simple website that will take data from the mysql database and display it on the page. I have problem: how to display multiple mysql records on web? this code only display the first record.
    ...
        select_input(Table,Id,Species,Dbh),

```
    repeat,

    format('<pre>', []),

    %swritef(S,'SELECT * FROM %t', [Table]),
    %prep(S, [] , row(Id, Species,Dbh) , []),

    write('Id = '),writeln(Id),
    write('Species = '),writeln(Species),
    write('Dbh = '),writeln(Dbh),

    format('</pre>', []),
```

...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swi prolog mysql + web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584861/swi-prolog-mysql-web)

Answer (score 0):

```
   fetch(Q):-
    odbc_fetch(Q, Row, []),
    (   Row == end_of_file
    ->  true
    ;   writeln(Row),
        fetch(Q)
    ).
```

finally got it - it display by row ... 
but how to display by column name?